# Web and its dependent assembly configuration

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a small scenario and trying to figure out the best way to do it.
Currently my website has a dependent assembly which has it's app.config. I have stored certain credentials in it which I use to access a third party API in my code.

I also have a test and live account for this account, I use Test account during my development, the problem is when I build my solution it only moves all the dlls from the project to my web BIN folder. There is no way I can change API Credentials in App.Config from test to live account when website is live. Each time I have to change the values in app.config, build the whole solution and move it live.

Is there a way to output app.config to web congig so I can change the values real time or read values from my web.config into my dependent project or any other best way to do it?

Looking forward to your replies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, assuming you are using Visual Studio 2010 is [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx).

You can specify certain web.config elements and values to be transformed for different build configurations (Debug, Test, Release, for example).